# Explanation of the passage from $\int_{N'}^N dN/N$ to $\ln N-\ln N'$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

While going through my text I got stuck in the derivation given in the picture.

[image]

($\Omega$ is a constant)

I don't know how to get the second step from the first step, also I don't know why ln is applied in the second step.

---

Translation (by an editor):

$$\int_{N'}^N dN/N = -\Omega \int_{t'}^t dt$$
$$\ln N-\ln N' = -\Omega (t-t')$$

Comment: Perhaps you could use the site http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to re-format your question.  It isn't readable in this form.

Comment: I agree with @Paul. I was about to edit your post, but then realised that it is difficult to understand what you mean. Do you mean the following? $$N^{N^{\prime}_{1/N}}dN=\alpha t^{t^{\prime}_{dt}}$$ This seems odd to me...(If this is what you mean, then the code is `$N^{N^{\prime}_{1/N}}dN=\alpha t^{t^{\prime}_{dt}}$`)

Comment: I understood that it is difficult to understand the codes I have typed so I have edited the question.

Comment: `Help!` is great in the Beatles catalog; not so great in question titles.

Answer (score 1):

The piece you seem to be missing is $\int{\frac{1}{x} dx}=\ln x +C$  Then $\int_M^N {\frac{1}{x} dx}=\ln N-\ln M$  You shouldn't have the same variable inside the integrand as in the limits of the integrand.